# jQuery .click() overwrites a tags

Tags: jquery, html, click, toggleclass

I'm stumped at the moment. I have a click() function implemented on .title to toggle its sibling (table) whether to show or hide. That works fine. My problem is that I have another click function inside .title which is on the a tag. When I click the a tag I want to keep the table open but .title over writes that and closes it and messes everything up. At the moment I have an onClick() on the a tag (which still doesn't work), it was done with jQuery .click() but I just can't get it right.

```
<script>
function dateChange(boatInput, dateInput){

         $("table").first().children().remove();
         $("table").first().load("availability.asp?boatType="+ boatInput +"&date="+ dateInput +"");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table").first().load("availability.asp?boatType=PowerCatamaran&date=currentDate", function(response, status, xhr){
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            $("table").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });


    $(".title").click(function(){
      $(this).next().toggleClass("hide");
      var boatName = $(this).next().attr('id');
      if(!$(this).next().hasClass('hide')){
          if(boatName == "SailingCatamaran"){
              $(this).next().load("#");
          }
          else if(boatName == "PowerCatamaran"){
              $(this).next().load("#");
          }
          else{
              $(this).next().load("#");
          }
      }
      $(this).children().last().toggleClass("hide");
      $(this).find('.dateSelect').toggleClass("hide");

    });
}); 
</script>

<div class="title">
        <h2>Catamarans</h2>
        <div class="dateSelect">
            <div class="prev">
                <p>Prev</p>
                <a href="#">< month</a>
                <a href="#">< week</a>
                <a href="#">< day</a>
            </div>

            <div class="next">
                <p>Next</p>
                <a href="#" onClick="dateChange('PowerCatamaran', 'nextMonth')">month ></a>
                <a href="#">week ></a>
                <a href="#">day ></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="expand hide">
            Click to Expand
        </div>
     </div>
```

So far the code is static. I just need some actual functionality working before making it all dynamic. I apologize for terrible code in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the propagation of the click eveht from the inside event by calling    [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$('<tag-selector>').click(function(event){
    //do your stuff
    event.stopPropagation()
});
```

Comment: @AkiraDawson no, the inside one. Can you share the tag click event code as well

Comment: If you ever hit Aussie, I'll buy you a damn beer.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - you might want to do some research on Google about `event.preventDefault()`, `event.stopPropagation()` and `return false;`; it is good to know when to use these and how they affect your JavaScript and/or jQuery code.

Comment: @Karl in the said case, it doesn't look like the default action is causing any problem so just preventing the propagation seemed to be enough

Comment: In `jQuery`, `return false;` equals `event.preventDefault();` plus `event.stopPropagation();`, but in plain old `JavaScript` that is not true, as `return false;` still allows the event to bubble up the `DOM`. That was my point in saying you should read more about it. ;-)

Comment: @Karl I know that.... in this context it does not matter as `stopPropagation` was called

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Sorry, I meant for those comments to go to Akira. Just realized that I mistakenly @ signed you. Now I understand why you are saying "I know already", my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty on CSS and jQuery selectors, but I think once you tag an element with a class, it applies to all elements that are children as well.

So the a's, p's, etc. in the div tagged .title also inherit class .title.

If you don't want that, I would suggest being more specific with the jQuery selector used to choose which elements get a .click() handler.

Perhaps:

```
$(".title > table").click(function(){...})
```

From jQuery ["Child Selector"](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) this says to apply the handler to all table elements that have a parent element in class .title

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure it specificity applied to jQuery, again, still sorta new to jQuery. But I found that the event.propagation() worked brilliantly, thank you for the reply though! Will definitely be used in the future for sure!